# jQuery getting these functions to work together

Tags: php, jquery, onsubmit, form-data

I'm new to jQuery and have tried looking around for an answer on how to do this. I have 2 functions and I would like both to work together. The one function is submitHandler and its used to hide a form and at the same time add a class to a hidden element to unhide it - ie a thank you for submitting h1. The other function is to grab the input data and display it onsubmit in the form. So the problem is that I can get that one to work but then the other doesnt. Ie on form submit I can see the data input but not the h1 Thank you message.

Here are the functions:

SubmitHandler:

```
    submitHandler: function() {


    $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").append(
    "<p>If you want to be kept in the loop...</p>" +
    "<p>Or you can contact...</p>"
    );
    $('h1.success_').removeClass('success_').addClass('success_form');
    $('#contactform').hide();

},
```

onsubmit="return inputdata()"

```
    function inputdata(){

                    var usr = document.getElementById('contactname').value;
                    var eml = document.getElementById('email').value;
                    var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;

                    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = usr + " " + eml + msg;
                    document.getElementById('out').style.display = "block";

                    return true;
            },
```

The form uses PHP and jQuery - I dont know about AJAX but after some reading even less sure. Please help me out I dont know what I'm doing and at the moment I am learning but its a long road for me still.

Thank you

The form:

```
          <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform" onsubmit="return inputdata()">
        <div class="_required"><p class="label_left">Name*</p><input type="text" size="50" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required" /></div><br/><br/>
        <div class="_required"><p class="label_left">E-mail address*</p><input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" /></div><br/><br/>
        <p class="label_left">Message</p><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="message" class="required"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
```

The PHP bit:

```
<?php
```

$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@bgv.co.za'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

}
```

}
?>

The Jquery Validate bit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contactform').validate({

       showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
       //restore the normal look
       $('#contactform div.xrequired').removeClass('xrequired').addClass('_required');
       //stop if everything is ok
       if (errorList.length == 0) return;
       //Iterate over the errors
       for(var i = 0;i < errorList.length; i++)
       $(errorList[i].element).parent().removeClass('_required').addClass('xrequired');
        },
```

Here is the full jQuery bit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').validate({

       showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
       //restore the normal look
       $('#contactform div.xrequired').removeClass('xrequired').addClass('_required');
       //stop if everything is ok
       if (errorList.length == 0) return;
       //Iterate over the errors
       for(var i = 0;i < errorList.length; i++)
       $(errorList[i].element).parent().removeClass('_required').addClass('xrequired');
        },

submitHandler: function() {             

    $('h1.success_').removeClass('success_').addClass('success_form');
    $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").append('#sadhu');
    $('#contactform').hide();

},
```

});
});

Latest edit - Looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').validate({

       showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
       //restore the normal look
       $('#contactform div.xrequired').removeClass('xrequired').addClass('_required');
       //stop if everything is ok
       if (errorList.length == 0) return;
       //Iterate over the errors
       for(var i = 0;i < errorList.length; i++)
       $(errorList[i].element).parent().removeClass('_required').addClass('xrequired');
        },

    function submitHandler() {             
        $('h1.success_').removeClass('success_').addClass('success_form');
        $("#content").empty();
        $("#content").append('#sadhu');
        $('#contactform').hide();
    },
    function inputdata() {
         var usr = document.getElementById('contactname').value;
         var eml = document.getElementById('email').value;
         var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
         document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = usr + " " + eml + msg;
         document.getElementById('out').style.display = "block";
    },
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#contactForm').submit(function() {
            inputdata();
            submitHandler();
        });
    });
```

});

Comment: Could you also post your corresponding HTML code???

Comment: Sure man, I added some more stuff. Here is a link the testspace:

http://www.bgv.co.za/testspace/contact_3.php

Comment: It seems there is an error in your jquery code...in the submitHandler function...it shows up on chrome's console when you right click -> Inspect element. It seems your selectors <code>$("#content").empty()</code> seems to throw an illegal token error...try surrounding it with single quotes and rerun the script to check. Also in your next line you have <code>$("#content").append(#sadhu)</code> - You need to either have it in single quotes or double quotes if including plain text! Try fixing this and seeing

Comment: Hiya Nupul,

Thank you for that, but the problem then is it returns a #sadhu in the thank you page instead of the form inputs - I'm trying to pull in the data the person has entered in the form and display it back to them with that Thank you header at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submitHandler function isn't called. That's why it doesn't work.

Add this to your code:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function() {
inputdata();
submitHandler();
```

});

EDIT:

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').validate({

showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
   //restore the normal look
   $('#contactform div.xrequired').removeClass('xrequired').addClass('_required');
   //stop if everything is ok
   if (errorList.length == 0) return;
   //Iterate over the errors
   for(var i = 0;i < errorList.length; i++)
   $(errorList[i].element).parent().removeClass('_required').addClass('xrequired');
},

submitHandler: function(form) {             
    $('h1.success_').removeClass('success_').addClass('success_form');
    $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").append('#sadhu');
    $('#contactform').hide();
    var usr = document.getElementById('contactname').value;
    var eml = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = usr + " " + eml + msg;
    document.getElementById('out').style.display = "block";
    form.submit();
}
});
});
```

Comment: Hiya Ewout, ah this could be the problem - but after trying it out the jquery bit just fails it might be as I'm not placing it correctly. So I've added the full script to my question at the top. Please see that and let me know or show me where to place this :)

Comment: Uh, I don't see you binding anything to the submit event as in my example in your code?

Comment: sure, but where do I put it before the: submitHandler: function() {
When I tried that copy and paste what you have then the jquery doesnt work anymore...

Comment: Hey I gave it a bash - please se my addition to my qustion above for how I applied it... but now it seems to have broken the jquery as none of the other things are working... it might be the way I've done it you help is appreciated :)

Comment: Didn't see that you were using the validation plugin... Remove the onsubmit in your HTML and try my updated code.

Comment: Cool thats definately better but still have an issue. For some reason when you submit the form it flashes up partly correct but then changes to relect the form input data with the form below (which should be hidden) and the h1 thank you - hidden...

You can test it out here> http://www.bgv.co.za/testspace/contact_3.php

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already been answered and this isn't directly regarding the question itself; more so regarding the code in the question. However, I can't post comments as I'm a brand new member, but I just thought I'd highlight a few things in your code! Mainly consistency regarding the use of jQuery.

In the function supplied for 'submitHandler' - you empty $('#content') and then append HTML to it. This will work, but an easier method would be using the .html() function; note that this function *can* be used to return the HTML contained inside an element; but that's when no arguments are supplied. When you supply an argument, it re-writes the content of the html element. Additionally, I would most likely use the .show() method on the h1 success element; if only for code readability.

For example:

```
submitHandler: function(){
    $('#content').html( "<p>If you want to be kept in the loop...</p>"
        + "<p>Or you can contact...</p>");
    $('h1.success_').show();
    $('contactform').hide();
}
```

As for inputdata() - you seem to have strayed off of the jQuery ethos here a little again, I'd aim for consistency when using jQuery personally - but also as the jQuery syntax makes the traditional javascript 'document.getElemen...' object look a bit outdated/it's extra to type. *At its most basic* jQuery is essentially best viewed as a wrapper for the document object - just with added syntactical sugar. Additionally, it allows you to chain methods - so the last two expressions can essentially be "dressed up" to look as one when using jQuery.

I'd personally use .val(), .html() and .css() functions; example:

```
function inputdata(){
    var usr = $('#contactname').val();
    var eml = $('#email').val();
    var msg = $('#message').val();

    $('#out').html( usr + " " + eml + msg )
    .css('display', 'block');

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CHange return true, to return false in the inputdata function